# Django model has foreignkey to self. I want to get count of children?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-tables2

I have a model as below which is hierarchical Group
The group has either a parent group or none

```
class AccGroup(models.Model):
    grpid = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    groupname = models.CharField(max_length=40, default="", verbose_name='Group Name')
    parentgrpid = models.ForeignKey('self',on_delete= models.SET_NULL,  blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Parent Group')
    printlevel = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Print Level')
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.groupname)
```

This group list is displayed in HTML Table using a template by sending a querylist as context

```
 
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Group Name</th><th>Parent Group</th><th>Print Level</th><th>Children</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     {% for group in grouplist %}                        
        <tr>
            <td><a  href="{% url 'groupupdate' menu.grpid %}" >                       
            {{group.groupname}}</a>
            </td>
            <td>{{group.parentgrpid}}</td> <td>{{group.printlevel}}</td> <td>{{group.accgroup__count}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}                      
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If there are child groups then I want to know how many child groups are under the group which I can print in  html table
How to get children group count from parent group object

Comment: Direct children, or should *grandchildren* also be counted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the direct children with:

```
myaccgroup.accgroup_set.count()
```

this will thus *not* take into account grand children, etc. Only the items tat are *one* layer below the *`myaccgroup`* object.

If you need this for a large number of `AccGroup`s, then you can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the queryset of `AccGroup`s:

```
from django.db.models import Count

AccGroup.objects.annotate(
    nchildren=Count('accgroup')
)
```

The `AccGroup` objects that arise from *this* querysete will have an extra attribute `.nchildren` that thus for each `AccGroup` will carry the number of *direct* children.

Comment: Yes I get the count in shell but how to have it in template ?

Comment: @user2035041: you calculate it in the view, pass it through the context, and render it in the template.

Comment: Where should I write the annotate code
In models.py or views.py?

Comment: @user2035041: normally the *view*, unless you will need this every time (so for all views), in that case it is worth doing this in a manager, but if this is seldomly used, in the relevant view(s).

Comment: Just a follow up 
What should be the syntax if Model Account has Foreignkey of AccGroup and I want count of Child Groups & Child Accounts simultaneously
```
AccGroup.objects.annotate(nchildren=Count('accgroup'), naccounts=Count('account'))
```
this does not work

Comment: @user2035041: can you please ask a *new* question and share the necessary details?